# The WAR in my EAR doesn't load log4j2 properly but the JAR does

Tags: java, wildfly, ear, log4j2

I have this skinny-war EAR file. It is supposed to be contained in a WildFly 8.2.0.Final application server.

```
- lib
  - log4j-api-2.1.jar
  - log4j-core-2.1.jar
- META-INF
  - application.xml
  - jboss-app.xml
  - log4j2.xml
  - MANIFEST.MF
- my-ejb.jar
- my-web.war (skinny war)
  - META-INF
    - MANIFEST.MF
  - WEB-INF
    - classes
      - ...
    - lib (empty since skinny war)
  - index.html
```

When I first start logging from `my-web.war`, I keep getting this message: `2015-03-04 11:04:22,806 ERROR [stderr] (default task-23) ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...` and no message is added to my log file.

However when I start logging from `my-ejb.jar`, I have no issue at all and the consequent logging from `my-web.war` is working fine as well.

How to have log4j2 properly used/configured in my EAR file so that I don't have to care that my ejb file is called first?

Files, as requested:

my-ejb.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Olivier
Class-Path: lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar lib/guava-18.0.jar lib/log4j-core-2.
 1.jar lib/log4j-web-2.1.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_25
```

my-web.war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Olivier
Class-Path: lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar lib/guava-18.0.jar lib/log4j-core-2.
 1.jar lib/log4j-web-2.1.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_25
```

Comment: Note, I've tried adding log4j-web-2.1.jar as well.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `Class-Path` from your WAR manifest? It might be trying to look in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Your manifest Class-Path entries are both redundant and incorrect. `A JAR format file (such as a .jar file, .war file, or .rar file) may reference a .jar file or directory by naming the referenced .jar file or directory in a Class-Path header in the referencing JAR file’s Manifest file. The referenced .jar file or directory is named **using a URL relative to the URL of the referencing JAR file.** ` The jar files in the EAR/lib directory should be available without manifest class path entries

Answer (score 0):

The `log4j2.xml` file must be in the classpath in order to be found.

Try putting it here:

```
my-web.war
   WEB-INF
      classes
          log4j2.xml
```

Comment: Where in the wildfly 10 can we put this file for the logging to be configured globally?

Answer (score -1):

Does my-ejb.jar MANIFEST.MF contains relative classpath to log4j jars? If you want to use your own log4j configuration, place file log4j2.xml to root of the ear and place jboss-app.xml to META-INF folder of the ear with such content:

```
<jboss-app>
<loader-repository>
org.myapp:loader=MyClassLoader
<loader-repository-config>
  java2ParentDelegation=false
</loader-repository-config>
</loader-repository>
</jboss-app>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed the MANIFEST.MF in my-ejb.jar does contain the classpath with the relative paths. I moved the log4j2.xml to the root of the ear and I adapted the jboss-app.xml to contain what you wrote, adapting `MyClassLoader` to `my-app.ear` which is the name of my EAR file. However after all those changes, the issue still occurs.

Comment: Is console log changed after modification? Can you show it?

Comment: Sure I can show it, but it didn't change at all: `2015-03-04 12:04:26,988 ERROR [stderr] (default task-41) ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...`

Comment: Can your show MANIFEST.MF from my-ejb.jar and my-web.war?

Comment: I've added those to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Its all are correct. Please, follow  the [link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/239572?start=0&tstart=0). I hope it helps you.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll add it as a module instead of inside my applications. Thanks!

Comment: This answer provides jboss-app.xml content suitable for JBossAS 5 & 6. It will be ignored in WildFly and JBossAS 7.x